# How do I create a 'route' in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, api, routes, hook

For my own sanity I'm trying to create a route for an ajax api that looks something like:

```
/api/<action>
```

I'd like wordpress to handle this route and delegate to the proper action with `do_action`. Does wordpress give me a hook to implement this? Where's a good spot?

Comment: There is a similar question to this one over on `wordpress.stackexchange.com`.  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26388/how-to-create-custom-url-routes

Answer (score 17):

You have to use [add_rewrite_rule](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule)

Something like:

```
add_action('init', 'theme_functionality_urls');

function theme_functionality_urls() {

  /* Order section by fb likes */
  add_rewrite_rule(
    '^tus-fotos/mas-votadas/page/(\d)?',
    'index.php?post_type=usercontent&orderby=fb_likes&paged=$matches[1]',
    'top'
  );
  add_rewrite_rule(
    '^tus-fotos/mas-votadas?',
    'index.php?post_type=usercontent&orderby=fb_likes',
    'top'
  );

}
```

This creates `/tus-fotos/mas-votadas` and `/tus-fotos/mas-votadas/page/{number}`, that changes the orderby query var for a custom one, which I handle in the pre_get_posts filter.

New variables can also be added using the `query_vars` filters and adding it to the rewrite rule.

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'custom_query_vars');
add_action('init', 'theme_functionality_urls');

function custom_query_vars($vars){
  $vars[] = 'api_action';
  return $vars;
}

function theme_functionality_urls() {

  add_rewrite_rule(
    '^api/(\w)?',
    'index.php?api_action=$matches[1]',
    'top'
  );

}
```

Then, handle the custom request:

```
add_action('parse_request', 'custom_requests');
function custom_requests ( $wp ) { 

  $valid_actions = array('action1', 'action2');

  if(
    !empty($wp->query_vars['api_action']) &&
    in_array($wp->query_vars['api_action'], $valid_actions) 
  ) {

    // do something here

  }

}
```

Just remember to flush the rewrite rules by visiting `/wp-admin/options-permalink.php` or calling [flush_rewrite_rules](http://codex.wordpress.org/flush_rewrite_rules) **only when needed**, since it's not a trivial process.

Comment: Here is the actual and complete solution by the wordpress: https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

Comment: Isn't that the same URL used on the first sencente of my response?

Comment: Sorry man, but I shared what worked for me so that it can help any other in future :)

Comment: That's ok, what I'm saying is that you shared the same link I used. Perhaps you would like to rephrase my original sentence to fit your idea?

Comment: Don't you need to call `add_rewrite_tag( '%api_action%', '([^&]+)' );` for this code to work?

Comment: @Flimm: the `custom_query_vars()` function is accomplishing the same thing as `add_rewrite_tag()` here.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are looking for wordpress [json-api](http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/) plugin,which is one of the nicely built plugins I have used,also very easily extendable.Good luck.